# Saving An Array Of Custom SKSpriteNodes Causes BAD ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access, nscoding

I am trying to save an array of custom sprites. Here's my class for doing so:

**SaveData.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SaveData : NSObject <NSCoding>

//persistent data
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *treeData;

+(instancetype)sharedSaveData;
-(void)save;

@end
```

**SaveData.m**

```
#import "SaveData.h"

@interface SaveData()

@end

@implementation SaveData

static NSString * const SaveDataTreeKey = @"treedata";

-(instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _treeData = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:SaveDataTreeKey];

        if (_treeData == nil) {
            _treeData = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

+(instancetype) sharedSaveData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

+(instancetype) loadInstance {
    NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [SaveData filePath]];
    if (decodedData) {
        SaveData* saveData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
        return saveData;
    }

    SaveData *data = [[SaveData alloc] init];

    if (data.treeData == nil)
        data.treeData = [NSMutableArray array];

    return data;
}

-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.treeData forKey:SaveDataTreeKey];
}

+(NSString*) filePath {
    static NSString* filePath = nil;
    if (!filePath) {
        filePath =
        [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedata"];
    }
    return filePath;
}

-(void) save {
    NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    [encodedData writeToFile:[SaveData filePath] atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

I've used this code before in another project, but I realized that I was only saving the types of objects and primitives that NSCoding allows (NSNumber, NSDictionary, etc). I'm trying to save an array of SKSpriteNodes (subclassed).

The SKSpriteNode subclass has a couple of booleans and of course it stores an texture, its size and its location on screen. Here's what I wrote for the NSCoding methods for my subclass called Producer:

**"Producer.m"**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.isEliminated = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"isEliminated"];
        self.isPlaced = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"isPlaced"];
        self.isSelected = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"isSeelcted"];
        self.isVisible = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"isVisible"];

        int x = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"x"];
        int y = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"y"];
        self.position = CGPointMake(x, y);

        [self createSelectionBox];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeBool:_isSelected forKey:@"isSelected"];
    [encoder encodeBool:_isEliminated forKey:@"isEliminated"];
    [encoder encodeBool:_isPlaced forKey:@"isPlaced"];
    [encoder encodeBool:_isVisible forKey:@"isVisible"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.position.x forKey:@"x"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.position.y forKey:@"y"];
}
```

**"Producer.h"**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface Producer : SKSpriteNode <NSCoding>

@property bool isEliminated;
@property bool isPlaced;
@property bool isSelected;
@property bool isVisible;

-(instancetype) initWithInvisibleState;
-(instancetype) initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)fileName;
-(instancetype) initWithImageFromBundleNamed:(NSString*)fileName;

-(void) select;
-(void) deselect;

@end
```

In my first scene, the producer objects are created and then stored in an array. I attempt to save this array by encoding using my SaveData.m class. Here's the call (from the first scene):

```
-(void) willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view {
    [SaveData sharedSaveData].treeData = _tree.data;
    [[SaveData sharedSaveData] save];
    [self removeAllChildren];
}
```

_tree.data is the array that I'm saving.

The app transitions to a new scene and then I try to retrieve the data from the saved file once again using the SaveData class by calling the following:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [SaveData sharedSaveData].treeData); //print out data in array
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm getting the following error:
`Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint and know what line exactly is throwing the error?

Comment: Yeah, I did. It reveals that printing out the SaveData treeData array is the issue. I've tried using the debugger to go deep within that call, but it doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: I was following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on encoding game data and it worked perfectly fine for me in another project. Anyways, I copied my good working version and made some modifications and it works fine. I honestly can't see where the issue was in the code that I posted. Some tiny mistake, I'm sure.

Comment: can you try logging out the sharedSavedData only?

Comment: I fixed the error....I don't know how though. As I said before, I copied my working version over from another project and tested it with a test project and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own question, but I decided to create another project to see if it was in how I was encoding the SKSpriteNode. It turns out that there's something wrong with my `SaveData` class.

Note: I used [Ray Wenderlich's solution](https://www.raywenderlich.com/63235/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-1-of-2) to create that class and modified it for my own uses.

I couldn't figure out which line of code was off, mainly because I didn't really come up with the code in the first place and I only have a partial understanding of how it all functions (I get the gist of it).

Here's what the working version of SaveData looks like just in case this helps anyone else in the future. Perhaps someone can tell me what the discrepancy is between the broken one (up top) and this version.

**SaveData.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SaveData : NSObject <NSCoding>

//persistent data
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *treeData;

+(instancetype)sharedSaveData;
-(void)save;
-(void)reset;

@end
```

**SaveData.m**

```
#import "SaveData.h"

@interface SaveData()


@end

@implementation SaveData


static NSString * const SaveDataTreeDataKey = @"treedata";

-(instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _treeData = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:SaveDataTreeDataKey];

        if (_treeData == nil)
            _treeData = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

+(instancetype) sharedSaveData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

+(instancetype) loadInstance {
    NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [SaveData filePath]];
    if (decodedData) {
        SaveData* saveData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
        return saveData;
    }

    //this happens if the game save file doesn't exist (first run of game)
    SaveData *data = [[SaveData alloc] init];

    if (data.treeData == nil) {
        data.treeData = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return data;
}


-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.treeData forKey:SaveDataTreeDataKey];
}

+(NSString*) filePath {
    static NSString* filePath = nil;
    if (!filePath) {
        filePath =
        [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"]; //saves in the Documents folder (might have to change this later)
    }
    return filePath;
}

-(void) save {
    NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    [encodedData writeToFile:[SaveData filePath] atomically:YES];
}

-(void) reset {
    _treeData = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self save];
}

@end
```

One more thing. To encode the SKSpriteNode, I created two methods in my SKSpriteNode subclass as follows:

From SKSpriteNode .m file

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];

        NSValue *decodedValue = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"position"];
        CGPoint point;
        [decodedValue getValue:&point];
        self.position = point;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];

    CGPoint point = self.position;
    NSValue *pointValue = [NSValue value:&point withObjCType:@encode(CGPoint)];
    [encoder encodeObject:pointValue forKey:@"position"];
}
```

The above code encodes the name of the sprite and its position. Just encode all instance variables necessary to preserve the object.